# malloc() error after initializing a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-allocation

I am trying to call `malloc` again after initializing another dynamically allocated array, but my program fails to run (though it can pass the compilation). Part of my code is as follows.

```
table = (Node **)malloc(m * sizeof(Node*));

for(i=0; i<=m; i++)
  table[i] = NULL;

table2 = (Node *)malloc(n * sizeof(Node));
```

The error information is like:

```
malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)
->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_si
ze == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (st
ruct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t
))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' 
failed.
```

The weirdest thing is that I have found that my program can run successfully after removing the second & third lines in my code above, in which `NULL` is assigned to `table[i]`. I am a little confused because I don't know what causes this `malloc` error. In addition, is it proper to assign `NULL` to newly allocated pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: @Olaf it is written C, but the error appears no matter I compile with gcc or g++.

Comment: Are the pointers returned by `malloc` valid? Show all relevant code. Which part of the assertion actually fails?

Comment: `i<=m` will access unallocated memory when i == m.

Comment: If that is C code: do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc`! Remove the C++-tag these are different languages, you would not add Java either just because they same some syntax.

Comment: Why would it be not ok to nullify newly allocated pointers? They do not have to ripen before usage;-)

Comment: I've never heard of the language "C/C++" is it new?

Comment: @Alex Here it is! I replaced ``<=`` with ``=`` and my code can run without any problem. This is the first time I have encountered that error message and it totally distracted me. I didn't notice the bug inside the ``for`` loop at all. Thanks so much!

Comment: Where exactly does that error occur? Use a debugger to step through your code! It is absolutely not clear if the assertion is from the first `malloc()` or from the second. Provide more information. IOW: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're welcome. valgrind would have told you about it.

Answer (score 5):

Isn't `i<=m` in the `for` loop going to go outside the region you allocated in the first `malloc()` call? You allocated `m` Node pointers in your table, and then set `m+1` entries equal to `NULL`.

Comment: It is and presents our good ol' "friend" _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: But the erros seems to pop up in `malloc` itself. Ok, "do not expect anything after UB"

Comment: You probably overwrote some memory that `malloc` uses for bookkeeping.

Comment: Are you talking to me? I'm not OP!

Comment: @Olaf mshindal is correct. It is the bug inside the ``for`` loop prevents the code from running successfully. I was totally distracted by the error message and tried to figure out what happened to the memory allocation. The message is really weird, isn't it?

Comment: @MarkZ: No need to explain to me. I did noticed already. You should still get your code in shape; I did not comment just for fun! For the message, I agree. That is quite a beast of an expression. Sorry, took me some time to realize it was not from your code.

Comment: Just reinforcing that once you step off the end of that array and corrupt memory, you can't really depend on the behavior or the error messages.  Likely you trashed something malloc was using/depending on.  Some allocates keep the user data and (internal allocation) list data together.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0; i<=m; i++)
  table[i] = NULL;
```

The second expression needs to be changed to `i < m`. You've allocated `m` slots. The range of access is `0...(m-1)`

`table`, size = 3

```
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
```